# Fabric crashlytics for Android

Tags: java, android, twitter, proguard, twitter-fabric

How can I enable Fabric Crashlytics in my app using Eclipse without using they Eclipse Plugin.

There reason why I ask is because, when I follow this [proguard-dexguard](https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/android/proguard-dexguard) steps for export my APK with Proguard. My App size does not reduce in size. as comparing when I used to use this :

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

But after enable Crashlytics I can not longer use the above line of code. I have to export as per web site says Export Crashlytics-enabled Android Application.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

try add below code in your proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class io.fabric.sdk.android.** { *; }
-keep interface io.fabric.sdk.android.** { *; }
-keep class com.digits.sdk.android.core.** { *; }
-keep interface com.digits.sdk.android.core.** { *; }
-keep class com.twitter.sdk.android.** { *; }
-keep interface com.twitter.sdk.android.** { *; }

-keep class io.fabric.** { *; }
-keep interface io.fabric.** { *; }
-keep class com.digits.** { *; }
-keep interface com.digits.** { *; }
-keep class com.twitter.** { *; }
-keep interface com.twitter.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep interface com.crashlytics.** { *; }
```